# How can I configure everything under an ExpandBar to follow it as it expands / collapses?

Tags: java, swt

I have an `ExpandBar` and underneath it there are additional components. Below is a simplified example of the version I am working with:

[image: Initial state.]

There is the `ExpandBar`, which I have copied from some sample, and there is the `Label` underneath it. When I collapse the `ExpandBar`, I want the `Label` to follow. To achieve that, I have the following:

```
bar.addExpandListener(new ExpandAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void itemCollapsed(ExpandEvent expandEvent) {
        item0.setHeight(0);
        shell.layout();
        super.itemCollapsed(expandEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemExpanded(ExpandEvent expandEvent) {
        item0.setHeight(height);
        shell.layout();
        super.itemExpanded(expandEvent);
    }
});
```

When I collapse, I get the expected result:

[image: Shell after collapse.]

However, when I try to expand again, the expand bar consists only of a scroll bar and does not actually expand:

[image: Expand Bar does not properly expand.]

I have tried to find help on the matter but am having a hard time finding anything similar. I have looked into the mechanics of `pack()` and `layout()` and have been unable to generate better results by packing the `bar` object.

How can I achieve the result I am after, that is, after collapsing, when I expand, the GUI should return to the state in the first picture?

Comment: Can you post your code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why are you futzing with heights and forcing layouts yourself? What kind of Composite and Layout is the parent of the ExpandBar and Label?

Comment: It is a `RowLayout()`, class that extends `Composite`. Without futzing around, the behavior is that the `ExpandBar` has a fixed height and some grey area if it is "collapsed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the expand/collapse events are fired before the new state of the expand bar is fully realized and re-layouting the parent uses the wrong widget bounds.

I was able to work around the issue in that I deferred thelayout code with `asyncExec()`.

Here is the snippet that I used to experiment with:

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setLayout( new RowLayout( SWT.VERTICAL ) );
  ExpandBar bar = new ExpandBar( shell, SWT.NONE );
  Composite composite = new Composite( bar, SWT.NONE );
  composite.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_YELLOW ) );
  ExpandItem item = new ExpandItem( bar, SWT.NONE, 0 );
  item.setText( "First item" );
  item.setHeight( 200 );
  item.setControl( composite );
  Label label = new Label( shell, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( "text" );

  bar.addExpandListener( new ExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemExpanded( ExpandEvent event ) {
      relayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemCollapsed( ExpandEvent event ) {
      relayout();
    }

    private void relayout() {
      display.asyncExec( () -> {
        bar.pack();
        shell.layout();
      });
    }
  } );

  shell.setSize( 400, 350 );
  shell.open();
  while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
      display.sleep();
    }
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I ended up getting mine to work using something very similar, `Display.getDefault().timerExec(1, () -> { });`but I think I like yours more.